# Position of link in LinkLabel

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a box of a fixed size to show some text and have a link in it that is clickable in the bottom right corner for editing.  Clicking this edit link shows a set of fields to fill in.

I tried LinkLabel, which does the trick, but, when I change the text, the size of the box changes.  I set autosize to false and longer text forces the link outside the box.  Short text puts the link to far up.

I could get fancy and calculate the position of the link and insert it at the appropriate place (adding new lines if needed), but I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way to do this.

Is there a better control for doing this or another way of doing this?

EDIT:
The boxes that are filled in are concatenated and replace the text in the linklabel. The Edit link is currently appended to this and a LinkArea (of the last 4 characters) is set.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: wpf or winforms? and what text do you change. Better make a screenshot or draw what you want

Comment: Did you try setting TextAlign = BottomRight ?

Comment: TextAlign would align all the text.  Only the link needs to be bottom right

Comment: What other text? I'm not aware that LinkLabel has other text than the linktext.

Comment: yes it does, I can do that bit.  You add text as normal then set a linkarea. In my case, it is the last 4 letters

Comment: Short answer: there is no special way of doing this. You want one control anchored to another control. I highly recommend you botch this practice and just put the label outside, for example on the top right corner.

Comment: You are right, or rather, there __is__ only one __text__ but also startindex and length to create a substring within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way.

I use a text box and position a linklabel in its corner.

textbox is readonly and disabled so it acts like a label and the backcolor is set to white to over-ride the disabled/readonly colour.

The edit link now stays put

Comment: Ah I see. Instead of a TextBox you also can use a plain Label as the Parent for the LinkLabel..

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a composite layout, for instance using a `Panel` with `Label/TextBox` (Dock = Fill) and `LinkLabel` (Dock = Bottom, TextAlign = MiddleRight) inside, like this

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var text = "I want a box of a fixed size to show some text and have a link in it that is clickable in the bottom right corner for editing.";
            int textSize = 50;
            var form = new Form { Padding = new Padding(8) };
            var panel = new Panel { Parent = form, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, Padding = new Padding(4) };
            var label = new Label { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = panel, AutoSize = false, Text = text, Height = textSize };
            var link = new LinkLabel { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Parent = panel, AutoSize = false, TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight, Text = "Edit" };
            panel.Location = form.DisplayRectangle.Location;
            panel.Width = form.DisplayRectangle.Width;
            panel.Height = panel.Padding.Vertical + link.Height + label.Height;
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]